# Create custom annotation in Java and use it when a method is called

Tags: java, annotations

What I want to do is to create a custom annotation to use it on a Service, and each time a method is called from there first execute something. For example:

```
@CustomAnnotation
public Class MyService{

   public void myMethod(){
      //do something
   }
}
```

And when myMethod is called, do something before its code is executed, and then do what it has to do. 
Is there any way to do that? I need to do it with annotations, using interfaces or inheritance for that is useless because is for each method, not just one.

I know how to scan a package to get the classes annotated, but I don't know how to check it at runtime when the app is running.

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/hunter-meta-3-092019.html

Comment: Thank you for the answers! The methods annotated with Around and Aspect are automatically executed? If I define the behavior there it should work well after running mvn install?

Comment: According to your original post it is more like "before advice", not "around", but you'll figure it out. Well... they *should* be automatically executed, *but* preparations must be made. I don't speak English well enough to explain briefly and clearly, but you should investigate "weaving". To make advices run, weaving must be made (either based on reflection or code-generation) and it somehow interferes compilation process, some specific compiler must be used or something like that. When I used aop, I had all spring infrastructure set up for me, so I don't know the details. But it must work

Comment: Thank you for your help! I followed a tutorial and it's not working, could you please help me? The question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260618/aspectj-does-not-execute-the-pointcut)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you need may be achieved by using AOP (aspect oriented programming).

Ive posted the code example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43272634/6948900). It executes some code before the annotated methods and doesn't execute for others.

AOP allows you to do that without intervention in code of method-containing classes, you may alter methods behavior without altering methods themselves and their invocation code. You may even skip method execution using this technique (using @Around advice). It is useful if you need security checks before allowing method execution, for example.